# setterm in bashrc on mac

Tags: bash, macos

```
setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 -blength 0
```

I found this line in my bashrc files on OSX. When I source the bashrc file, bash tells me the command "setterm" is not found. I can see the man page for setterm though. Does it make sense to have setterm on OSX or is it only for LINUX OS?

Comment: The only `setterm` man page I find on OS X is for the C function, not a shell command. The shell command doesn't exist on OS X.

Comment: Linux is open source, so you should be able to find the source code to the `setterm` command, and try compiling it on OS X.